# Is mongoDB or Cassandra better than MySQL for large datasets?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, cassandra, database

In our (currently MySQL) database there are over 120 million records, and we make frequent use of complex JOIN queries and application-level logic in PHP that touch the database. We're a marketing company that does data mining as our primary focus, so we have many large reports that need to be run on a daily, weekly, or monthly basis.

Concurrently, customer service operates on a replicated slave of the same database.

We would love to be able to make these reports happen in real time on the web instead of having to manually generate spreadsheets for them. However, many of our reports take a significant amount of time to pull data for (in some cases, over an hour).

We do not operate in the cloud, choosing instead to operate using two physical servers in our server room.

Given all this, what is our best option for a database?

Comment: NoSQL systems are typically very weak at joining data. I would stick with an RDBMS unless you model your data differently. It will probably give you the best running queries.

Comment: You will probably end up with more trouble using for example Cassandra because your data was modelled to confirm to Relational structure. Essentially you will have to remodel everything and then try optimising NOSQL solution. Considering you already have some expertise with MySQL you will probably optimise it easier. Also Cassandra is a bit buggy compared to MySQL. So try optimising your queries as other answers mentioned and definitely go for SSDs instead of plate drives. Keeping large part of dataset in RAM will also greatly help so consider InnoDB engine to help you with that.

Comment: Also one simple thing to consider, just to test some assumptions could be to replicate your database to another machine onto a RamDisk (you could even use some HighEnd workstation not a server) and then run some queries on it. You could even set-up some A/B testing meaning some report generation (since they are all reads) would target your server and others will target this test machine. If you get much better performance when reading from test machine it will tell you how much improvement you can expect if you improve HDD I/O .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're going the wrong way about the problem.

Thinking if you drop in NoSQL that you'll get better performance is not really true. At the lowest level, you're writing and retrieving a fair chunk of data. That implies your bottleneck is (most likely) HDD I/O (which is the common bottleneck).

Sticking to the hardware you have momentarily and using a monolithic data storage isn't scalable and as you noticed - has implications when wanting to do something in real-time.

What are your options? You need to scale your server and software setup (which is what you'd have to do with any NoSQL anyway, stick in faster hard drives at some point).
You also might want to look into alternative storage engines (other than MyISAM and InnoDB - for example, one of better engines that seemingly turn random I/O to sequential I/O is [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com)).

Implementing faster HDD subsystem would also aid to your needs (<s>[FusionIO](http://www.fusionio.com/)</s>  if you have the resources to get it).

Without more information on your end (what the server setup is, what MySQL version you're using and what storage engines + data sizes you're operating with), it's all speculation.

Comment: Main server is running CentOS 5.4, Intel Xeon dual core 3GHz, 32GB of RAM, and 500GB of hard disk space in RAID 5 configuration. MySQL version is 5.0.77. PHP version is 5.1.6. The database is almost entirely in MyISAM. We don't use blobs and most fields in the database are minute varchar (under 64) or smallint/tinyint. There are a handful of text fields.

Comment: Looks like you could definitely benefit from TokuDB storage engine, or even InnoDB. They simply scale better and perform better due to the way they store and operate on data. MyISAM performance deteriorates with larger data sets. 32 gigs of RAM means that entire working dataset might fit the RAM if engine used is InnoDB, which would definitely be a great solution for your case.

Comment: Is there a way to hotswap storage engines without affecting production operations? Perhaps through some replication gymnastics?

Comment: A RAID 10 configuration will get you roughly 3x the write performance of a RAID 5 configuration, and a slightly improved read performance. You just need twice the number of disks! :-/

Comment: We're planning on going to RAID 10 with our new server hardware, including using SSDs instead of mechanical drives for some things.

Comment: @Uthr - with MyISAM - no, hotswapping will force reordering data to conform to new storage engine's standard so all indexes and data will be rebuilt.

Comment: Alright, thank you. You've been a great help! We'll look into switching to TokuDB when we upgrade our hardware this month.

Comment: Good luck with your new hardware and software setup! :)

Answer (score 9):

Cassandra still needs Hadoop for MapReduce, and MongoDB has limited concurrency with regard to MapReduce...

... so ...

... 120 mio records is not that much, and MySQL should easily be able to handle that. My guess is an IO bottleneck, or you're doing lots of random reads instead of sequential reads. I'd rather hire a MySQL techie for a month or so to tune your schema and queries, instead of investing into a new solution.

If you provide more information about your cluster, we might be able to help you better. "NoSQL" by itself is not the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

As much as I'm not a fan of MySQL once your data gets large, I have to say that you're nowhere near needing to move to a NoSQL solution.  120M rows is not a big deal: the database I'm currently working with has ~600M in one table alone and we query it efficiently.  Managing that much data from an ops perspective is the problem; querying it isn't.

It's all about proper indexes and the correct use of them when joining, and secondarily memory settings.  Find your slow queries (mysql slow query log FTW!), and learn to use the *explain* keyword to understand whey they are slow.  Then tweak your indexes so your queries are efficient.  Further, make sure you understand MySQL's memory settings. There are great pages in the docs explaining how they work, and they aren't that hard to understand.

If you've done both of those things and you're still having problems, make sure disk I/O isn't an issue. *Then* you should look in to another solution for querying your data if it is.

NoSQL solutions like Cassandra have a lot of benefits.  Cassandra is fantastic at writing data. Scaling your writes is very easy--just add more nodes!  But the tradeoff is that it's harder to get the data back out.  From a cost perspective, if you have expertise in MySQl, it's probably better to leverage that and scale your current solution until it hits a limit before completely switching your underlying architecture.